# Android: How to read dynamic nested Json

Tags: android, json, nested

I have one Json that is not with specific parameters, in one moment can be with 2 children and after some time can be with 3 children. 
I implement one function but is hardcoded and if they are have some changes on Json it will not work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Json:

```
{
"topics":[
  {
     "idTopic":"24",
     "level":"1",
     "title":"Topic 0",
     "folder":true,
     "expanded":true,
     "children":[
        {
           "idTopic":"25",
           "level":"2",
           "title":"Topic 1",
           "folder":true,
           "expanded":true,
           "children":[

           ]
        },
        {
           "idTopic":"26",
           "level":"2",
           "title":"Topic 2",
           "folder":true,
           "expanded":true,
           "children":[
              {
                 "idTopic":"27",
                 "level":"3",
                 "title":"Topic 2-1",
                 "folder":true,
                 "expanded":true,
                 "children":[

                 ]
              },
              {
                 "idTopic":"28",
                 "level":"3",
                 "title":"Topic 2-2",
                 "folder":true,
                 "expanded":true,
                 "children":[

                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "idTopic":"29",
           "level":"2",
           "title":"Topic 3",
           "folder":true,
           "expanded":true,
           "children":[
              {
                 "idTopic":"30",
                 "level":"3",
                 "title":"Topic 3-1",
                 "folder":true,
                 "expanded":true,
                 "children":[

                 ]
              },
              {
                 "idTopic":"31",
                 "level":"3",
                 "title":"Topic 3-1-1",
                 "folder":true,
                 "expanded":true,
                 "children":[

                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
 ],
 "success":true
}
```

Read Json:

```
 JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                if(mainObj != null){
                    JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("topics");
                    if(list != null){
                        for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
                            JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
                            if(elem != null){
                                JSONArray prods = elem.getJSONArray("children");
                                if(prods != null){
                                    for(int j = 0; j < prods.length();j++){
                                        JSONObject innerElem = prods.getJSONObject(j);
                                        if(innerElem != null){

                                            String myId = innerElem.getString("idTopic");
                                            String children = innerElem.getString("children");

                                            getTopicsId.add(myId);

                                            if(!children.equals("[]")){

                                                JSONArray childrens = innerElem.getJSONArray("children");
                                                for(int k = 0; k < childrens.length();k++) {
                                                    JSONObject innerElem1 = childrens.getJSONObject(k);

                                                    String myId1 = innerElem1.getString("idTopic");
                                                    String children1 = innerElem1.getString("children");

                                                    getTopicsId.add(myId1);

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hi, if you for example to get "title":"Topic 1"... in java for example you get JsonObject named object.  . . String title = object.getJSONObject("topics").getJSONObject("children").getString("title");

Comment: no need to get individual nests.. just the whole JSON you can navigate along

Comment: Still using traditional method to parse JSON?? Go with GSON my friend. Create POJO classes and you are done with.

Comment: check this tutorial maybe u can get some logic off it: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-1/ , i dont see how u cannot use the size of the children and also u can play around with the JSONobject or array,if one gives an error then try the other